# Data transformation into adjacency matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, adjacency-matrix

I am having a bit trouble with transforming a dataset into an adjacency matrix. The data is from events. It has five variables: the id of the event (id), the ids of the organizations present (org1, org2, org3 - up to three were coded per event), a dichotomous location information (BP), and the number of participants (nr_participants). It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6
     id org1  org2  org3     BP nr_participants
  <int> <fct> <fct> <fct> <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1 15    23    0         1               0
2     2 11    11    13        1          127000
3     3 23    13    28        1             500
4     4 11    11    13        1             500
5     5 29    28    23        1           50000
6     6 31    49    0         1               0
```

I would like to get from this data two adjacency matrices. In both, the unique organizations are the rows and the columns (109 unique values). So based on the `head` table above, the data should look like:

```
    15  23  0   11  13  28  29  31  49
15                                  
23                                  
0                                   
11                                  
13                                  
28                                  
29                                  
31                                  
49
```

**In the first case:** the cells should be the sum of the nr_participants in the events organized by any given pair of organizations.

So for example for the short head table, it should look like:

[image]

**In the second case:** the cells should be the share of 1s in BP, from all the events organized by any given pair of organization.

Here is a 50 obs. sample of the data:

```
sample <- structure(list(id = c(4262L, 5140L, 3171L, 2167L, 4618L, 1668L, 
771L, 4975L, 3563L, 4014L, 5695L, 1412L, 3752L, 4165L, 5282L, 
5538L, 3339L, 3555L, 945L, 1620L, 3187L, 4955L, 4436L, 4609L, 
4205L, 4402L, 2156L, 3745L, 895L, 5774L, 4969L, 114L, 4600L, 
4188L, 5315L, 1092L, 3726L, 1488L, 1619L, 2853L, 5298L, 3095L, 
502L, 2711L, 789L, 185L, 293L, 3456L, 5605L, 2783L), org1 = structure(c(23L, 
16L, 4L, 48L, 9L, 4L, 48L, 1L, 4L, 48L, 25L, 4L, 4L, 48L, 10L, 
26L, 3L, 4L, 49L, 4L, 4L, 26L, 48L, 49L, 48L, 22L, 11L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 49L, 31L, 51L, 48L, 26L, 21L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 11L, 1L, 4L, 82L, 
4L, 54L, 48L, 83L, 1L, 48L, 49L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "42", "43", "44", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", 
"52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "62", "64", 
"65", "67", "70", "72", "73", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", 
"81", "82", "83", "84", "87", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "98", 
"100", "102", "103", "104", "105", "107", "109", "111", "114", 
"117", "120", "122"), class = "factor"), org2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 28L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 12L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 30L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", "16", "17", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", 
"32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "39", "42", "44", "46", "47", 
"48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "54", "56", "57", "58", "59", "61", 
"64", "67", "68", "73", "81", "83", "84", "88", "89", "90", "94", 
"99", "100", "104", "106", "107", "109", "117", "118", "120", 
"122", "124"), class = "factor"), org3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 11L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 46L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "13", "15", "16", "17", "19", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "31", "32", "34", "35", "36", "39", 
"42", "43", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "52", "54", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "63", "66", "68", "73", "77", "85", "107", "117", 
"120", "122", "123"), class = "factor"), BP = structure(c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), format.stata = "%9.0g"), nr_participants = c(50, 
0, 0, 0, 80, 0, 40, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 80, 50, 36, 50, 0, 
587, 0, 0, 0, 200, 20, 200, 160, 5, 0, 341, 20, 1600, 250, 20, 
0, 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 500, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 50, 382, 300, 100
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

How do I fill the matrix with the sum and share values as defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `outer` -

```
#get the column numbers with 'org' in it
cols <- grep('org', names(df))
#Get all the unique org values. 
unique_orgs <- unique(unlist(df[cols]))

#Function to calculate sum of nr_participants where 
#the two numbers exist in the same row
calculate_sum <- function(x, y) {
  sum(df$nr_participants[rowSums(df[cols] == x) > 0 | 
                         rowSums(df[cols] == y) > 0])  
}
#Use outer to apply it for every unique values
mat <- outer(unique_orgs, unique_orgs, Vectorize(calculate_sum))
#assign row and column names
dimnames(mat) <- list(unique_orgs, unique_orgs)

mat

#       15     11     23     29     31     13     28     49      0
#15      0 127500  50500  50000      0 128000  50500      0      0
#11 127500 127500 178000 177500 127500 128000 178000 127500 127500
#23  50500 178000  50500  50500  50500 178000  50500  50500  50500
#29  50000 177500  50500  50000  50000 178000  50500  50000  50000
#31      0 127500  50500  50000      0 128000  50500      0      0
#13 128000 128000 178000 178000 128000 128000 178000 128000 128000
#28  50500 178000  50500  50500  50500 178000  50500  50500  50500
#49      0 127500  50500  50000      0 128000  50500      0      0
#0       0 127500  50500  50000      0 128000  50500      0      0
```

Comment: this does not work for me. With the sample data I provided I get an error: Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': comparison of these types is not implemented
In addition: Warning message:
In rowSums(df[cols] == x) :

Comment: That is because you have data with `factor`. Replace the `unique_orgs` line with `unique_orgs <- unique(as.character(unlist(df[cols])))` and try again. That should work.